# Oracle - How to Convert VARCHAR to DATETIME format

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle10g

I am using `Oracle10g` database in which a table contains a Column with `Date` DataType. I am using the following query to get the record:

```
 select to_char(START_TIME, 'YYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') from table;
```

So from above query, the result will be of type `VARCHAR`. I have tried `to_Date()` method but resulted in displaying only `DATE`. Can i convert `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME` format? The result should be of type `DATETIME`. Please help me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: As your stated problem is converting strings to dates (which in Oracle are the same as datetimes) you need to show us a sample of the original data and the format mask which you're using.   Unless you don't want us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's `Date` type fields contain date/time values, therefore converting it to `Datetime` does not make any sense (it's already datetime)

Read more about oracle date types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006006)

Answer (score 5):

an Oracle `date` contains both date and time so you can consider it a `datetime` (there is no datatype of `datetime` in Oracle). how is DISPLAYS when you select it is entirely up to your client. the default display setting is controlled by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. If you're just using the date in your pl/sql block then just assign it into a `date` datatype and select into that variable without `to_char` and it will work just fine and contain whatever time component is present in your table.

to control the display, for example using `nls_date_format`:

```
SQL> select a from datetest;
A
---------
19-FEB-13

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYMMDD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select a from datetest;
A
---------------
130219 07:59:38
```

but again, this is only for display.

Comment: @Avadhani - 'it doesn't work' is incredibly unhelpful. What doesn't work - you get a different format, or an error? Are you doing exactly what DazzaL showed or your own variation?

Comment: @AlexPoole as the answerer says at the end of the answer- "but again, this is only for display". I am working on BIRT reports, i want to use the query in IDE and the resulted columns will be used in designing the report. CAn u help in that way....????

Comment: @Avadhani - DazzaL said to just treat them as dates throughout. You may need to change the default date display format in your IDE so that it shows the time portion - it will have some way to set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. I'm not clear how that feeds into the report though.

Comment: @Avadhani I don't use eclipse/BIRT but perhaps this link is of use? http://birtworld.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/birt-formatting-numbers-and-dates.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the Date datatype will meet your needs but you will have to jump through some hoops every time to get the exact time out of it. Definitely use the Timestamp datatype.